# Parsing BTC jQuery calculator to USD

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this investment calculator in javascript/jquery. It calculates the profit someone would have, based on specific plans. It's written to work with bitcoin values, which goes like this `0.36000000 BTC`. I just need to parse it to `3,6` format.

https://pastebin.com/DZvWxEkt

```
jQuery(function($){
    //Setting calculator
    var percent     = [0.36,0.46,0.52];
    var minMoney    = [0.001,5.001, 10.001];
    var maxMoney    = [5,10,99999999.9999];
    $("#btc_amt").val(minMoney[0]);

    /*calculator*/
    function calc(){
        money = parseFloat($("#btc_amt").val());
        id = -1;
        var length = percent.length;
        var i = 0;
        do {
            if(minMoney[i] <= money && money <= maxMoney[i]){
                id = i;
                i = i + length;
            }
            i++
        }
        while(i < length)

        if(id != -1){
            profitHourly = money / 100 * percent[id];
            profitHourly = profitHourly.toFixed(8);
            profitDaily = profitHourly * 24;
            profitDaily = profitDaily.toFixed(8);
            profitWeekly = profitDaily * 7;
            profitWeekly = profitWeekly.toFixed(8);
            profitMonthly = profitDaily * 30;
            profitMonthly = profitMonthly.toFixed(8);


            if(money < minMoney[id] || isNaN(money) == true){
                $("#profitHourly").text("Error!");
                $("#profitDaily").text("Error!");
                $("#profitWeekly").text("Error!");
                $("#profitMonthly").text("Error!");
                //$("#total_profit").text("Error!");
            } else {
                $("#profitHourly").text(profitHourly + " BTC");
                $("#profitDaily").text(profitDaily + " BTC");
                $("#profitWeekly").text(profitWeekly + " BTC");
                $("#profitMonthly").text(profitMonthly + " BTC");
                //$("#total_profit").text(profitTotal + " BTC");
            }
        } else {
            $("#profitHourly").text("Error!");
            $("#profitDaily").text("Error!");
            $("#profitWeekly").text("Error!");
            $("#profitMonthly").text("Error!");
            //$("#total_profit").text("Error!");
        }
        if(money >= 0.001 && money <= 5 ){
            $('#active-plan').text('0.36% Hourly profit');
            $("#h_id1").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if(money >= 5.001 && money <= 10 ){
            $('#active-plan').text('0.46% Hourly profit');
            $("#h_id2").prop("checked", true);
        }
        if(money >= 10.001 ){
            $('#active-plan').text('0.52% Hourly profit');
            $("#h_id3").prop("checked", true);
        }
    }
    calc();
    if($("#btc_amt").length){
        calc();
    }
    $("#btc_amt").keyup(function(){
        calc();
    });
    $("#h_id1").change(function(){
          if ($(this).is(':checked')){
              $('#btc_amt').val('0.001');
          }
          calc();
      });
      $("#h_id2").change(function(){
          if ($(this).is(':checked')){
              $('#btc_amt').val('5.001');
          }
          calc();
      });
      $("#h_id3").change(function(){
          if ($(this).is(':checked')){
              $('#btc_amt').val('10.001');
          }
          calc();
      });
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
    });
```

Comment: You mean trimming away the "BTC" text, convert to number and multiplying with 10? Anything you have already tried?

Comment: Got it working, thank you. Just changed the number of `toFixed(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, thank you. Just changed the number of `toFixed(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.getJSON( "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json", 
    function( data) {
    var amountInBtc = 0.005; //convert 0.005 btc to usd
    var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);
    var amount = amountInBtc * exchangeRate;
    console.log(amount);
    });
```

Read the full post [here](http://techcerberus.blogspot.com.ng/2018/01/simple-bitcoin-calculator.html)